# How can I apply CSS rules to directly-adjacent sibling elements?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I understand how to use the `:hover` selector, but I'd like to apply rules in a similar way to directly-adjacent elements. For example, if I have links A, B, C and D in a flat list, I'd like B and D to be applied to when I mouse over C.

The most intuitive method that comes to mind is overlapping the `<a>` tags, so that the rule is applied to the neighboring text nodes, like so:

`<a>A<a>B</a></a>`

If I apply a style to the first anchor, it should affect both A and B, etc.

I'm interested in a solution that's both HTML5-, IE- and Chrome-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

First, tags in well-formed HTML have to be self-contained -- `<a><b></a></b>` is incorrect. Consider for a second, what the matching `href`s would point to. If you include B into A's element, it will share all the attributes: both the one that sets its style and the one that determines where it links to. That you can't separate those out should indicate that this might be the wrong way to go about it. Canonically, we say that HTML should represent the *structure* of the document and what you're looking to change here is the *style*.

If we were to look at [some CSS selector reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), we would find ones similar to `:hover`. `+` and `~` should look useful, but in fact gives us *all* the elements before and after, which isn't exactly what you're looking for.

The most sane way to so this, I think, needs JavaScript. Check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrdn5y94/3/) for a demonstration. (I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) here.)